# haskell hashtable in hashtable?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, hashtable

I have two questions regarding hashtable implementation in haskell:

1. can I create hashtable in side hashtable? Meaning, use a hashtable as the value of a hashtable.
2. Can a hashtable has different type of key and value pair?

I did research on Data.Map and Data.HashTable. It seems I can not do that.
The only possible tool is Data.Tuple seems like.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking: (1) Are you concerned specifically with hash tables or with any key-value dictionaries/maps?  (`Data.Map` is a dictionary but not a hash table.)  (2) Are you asking whether you can have a hash table of hash tables?  (3) Are you asking whether you can have a "heterogeneous" hash table – one which maps different types of keys to different types of values?  (4) How do tuples fit in to this?  They're very different from hash tables/dictionaries.

Comment: yes to 1. and 2. if you're talking about `Map k a`, you'll have to [read up on typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) to instantiate `k` and `a` with what you want...

Comment: Okay, **how** did you research [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map) and say "I can not do that"? The type is `Map k v` where you can already see that the type for the `k`eys is different than the one for the `v`alues, so answer to 2 is yes. Also there is no restriction over what `v` can be so it can be `Map k' v'` as in `Map k (Map k' v')` which is a yes to question 1.

Answer (score 3):

> can I create hashtable in side hashtable? Meaning, use a hashtable as the value of a hashtable.

Yes.

> Can a hashtable has different type of key and value pair?

In any given hash table, all keys must have the same type, and all values must have the same type, but the keys may have different types than the values.